# Does @Asynchronous in EJB 3.1 closes/releses the connection when the Async method is completed

Tags: asynchronous, jakarta-ee, connection-pooling, ejb-3.1

In the EJB 3.1, we have annotated a method with @Asynchronous and using Future.get to fetch the results.

Question is when we do future.get(), does the database connections from the connection pool and resources are released which was being used in that async method?

Comment: You need to show some code otherwise it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 3):

Database connections are closed according to your configured connection pooling policy of the used application server.

When talking about session beans and container managed transactions, the connection is returned at the end to the transaction scope of the called business method.

Since session beans with `@Asynchronous` annotations do not support transaction propagation (e.g. see EJB 3.2 spec 4.5.3), a new transaction is created with every call to a business method if the method is configured with `REQUIRED` or `REQUIRES_NEW`. Thus, this transaction scope ends with the called business method returning.

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance they are :)  Otherwise using @Asynchronous would quickly lead to application crash due to lack of resources...

Anyway as resources are stored using Thread Local storage in Java-ee and as @Asynchronous defer the execution to a dedicated thread, the resources used there (including JCA Connection - and so database one) are also dedicated to the @Asynchronous method execution (not inherited from the caller thread).

Comment: Yes. We are seeing application crashes in the production in the multiuser environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The question is not answered. Does it closes the connection?

Comment: it does not close it, it releases it to the Datasource connection pool

Comment: You may have an issue regarding the @Asynchonous thread pool size and your database connection pool size. The thread pool size configuration is specific to your application server provider

Comment: Thanks Gab for your reply

Comment: Any parameters to limit the number of @Asynchronous threads spawned in the system/application?